# Select entries filtering rows with same field by lowest second_field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like:

```
id(int)    flag(int)    price(float)

1          0            50
2                       400
3          4            200
4          3            150
5          3            100
6          3            400
7          2            120
```

I'd like to select all rows that have distinct `flag`, choosing the lowest `price` on every group of `flag`
So, in this example I'd get:

```
id(int)    flag(int)    price(float)

1          0            50
2                       400
3          4            200
5          3            100
7          2            120
```

Note that `flag` is not mandatory, so it can have a value (int) or nothing (null).

Regards

EDIT:

Just to make it mre clear.

I want to select all the rows that have an `id` and a `price`, all of them, without filtering by price.
Then I'd like to join only the row with the lowest price from each group of `flags`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id, flag, price
FROM tbl t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM tbl tt
  WHERE t.flag = tt.flag
    AND (tt.price < t.price 
         OR (tt.price = t.price AND t.id < tt.id)));
```

And here's an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9249b/1) for it.

Comment: That's working right with the sqlfiddle data, however it's not working correctly with a view. Could it be because of the fact that it's a view?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter if it's a table or a view (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9d8f/1). When you say it's not working correctly, what exactly do you mean? It's giving you incorrect results?

Comment: It's returning more than 1 flag with the same number (and thus not the lowest price). What could be wrong?

Comment: I found a bug with your query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bca21/1  look at the prices. There are two equal prices with the same flag. In that case I'd like to get only 1 row (no matter which one as they are equal for me)

Comment: Ok, thought you wanted both rows in that case. I've changed my answer to reflect that, and it now works fine with that new data set.

Comment: That's really close to what I'm looking for, but there is still another problem. Only 1 row without a flag appears (even if there are more than 1 rows with different ```id```)

Comment: Can you create an sqlfiddle for that? You just one row without a flag in the final result? And what's the criteria? The one with the lowest price? Check this sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3396f/2).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15428/discussion-between-alexandernst-and-joao)

Answer (score 2):

The following query finds the min price for each flag and then joins them to the original data to get the id (and other information on the row).

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select flag, min(price) as minprice
      from table t
      group by flag
     ) tsum
     on (tsum.flag = t.flag or tsum.flag is null as t.flag is null) and
        (tsum.minprice = t.price)
```

Comment: This is wrong, `tsum` will always have a single row, you need to use `group by`.

Comment: Sure, no problem, MySQL should throw an error in that situation, as Oracle does with its `not a single-group group function` message.

Comment: @João . . . MySQL definitely does not throw an error in this situation.  In fact, the documentation describes it as a feature, called "hidden columns".  As I've said before, MySQL afficionados defend or like this.  The rest of us just scratch our heads wondering why a SQL engine accepts broken SQL.

Comment: Indeed, what they call "hidden columns", most call non-standard sql. :-)

Comment: Would that change if I had a view instead a table? :/

Comment: @alexandernst . . . The query would be the same with a view and a table.  For a table with an index on (flag, price), Joao's approach is probably faster.  For a view, it is unclear which has the performance advantage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you need the Id column, if not you just need to do this

```
SELECT flag, MIN(price) as price FROM Table GROUP BY flag
```

If you need it you have to do this

```
SELECT TBL1.*
FROM table TBL1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT flag, MIN(price) as price FROM table GROUP BY flag) TBL2
ON TBL1.flag = TBL2.flag AND TBL1.price = TBL2.price
WHERE TBL2.price IS NOT NULL
```

This last query uses the result of the grouping, join again with the original table and then filter the rows where the price was different of the min